# How much does the Portable Forge used by the 5e artificer weigh?

Tags: dnd-5e, artificer

The description does not make clear if the Portable Forge is a separate object as it was in 3.5e, or if it works as a proficiency with a set of tools, as with thieves tools, used to forge items.

Comment: Which version of the Artificer are you talking about? The separate [artificer class in this UA](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/1_UA_Artificer_20170109.pdf) doesn't seem to mention a portable forge.

Comment: It looks like you're using a homebrew version of the artificer as posted [here on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/UnearthedArcana/comments/89i9dd/5e_the_artificer_revised_again/). If you can confirm that is the source you're using, then we should have the necessary context to try and answer your question!